# What should I do when my DOB changed after I have been approved for a J-1 visa due to Hukou cancellation

Tags: usa, chinese-citizens, j1-visas

I'm a Chinese citizen. When I was 17, my parents filed a Hukou(household registry) using my name but a different date of birth for me without telling me. I was a minor back then, I had no clue about what is a Hukou whatsoever. My parents told me they have canceled the old Hukou, I need to use the newly filed Hukou ever since. I used the new Hukou to go to college, go to graduate school. Now 14 years have passed, I’m about to get my PhD degree.

However, on Jan. 2020, the Hukou management authority of public safety bureau informed me that I possessed two Hukous, pursuant to the regulations, I need to cancel the one filed latter and keep the original one. It was until that time did I know I possessed two Hukous, my parents didn’t cancel the old Hukou.

I applied for a passport using the newly filed Hukou with wrong date of birth in 2016. I have been approved for three US visas with this passport:

1. In 2016, I have been approved for a one-year J-1 visa, I used it to travel to the US as a visiting scholar for 14 months.
2. In 2017, I have been approved for a one-year B1/2 visa, I used it to travel to the US as a tourist for a little over a month.
3. In 2019, I have been approved for a one-year J-1 visa, I’m planning to use it to travel to the US as a visiting scholar in 2020.

I’ve been ten-fingered each time during the visa interview.

Now that the Hukou management authority has canceled my Hukou with the wrong date of birth, and they issued a certificate of Hukou cancellation for me stating that I possessed two Hukous and they canceled the one with wrong date of birth. What should I do so I can continue to travel to the US as a visiting scholar?

1. Inform the US embassy of the Hukou cancellation and try to correct the date of birth on my US visa? If so, what document should I submit?
2. Will it be approved to change the date of birth on my current J-1 visa due to Hukou cancellation? Will I be barred from entering the US because of this?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused a little. Which of the dates of birth is the correct one? The original or the one filed more recently? (Or in other words, were your parents trying to correct a DOB that was originally filed incorrectly?)

Comment: Presumably your passport has the wrong DoB too? If so you probably need to start by correcting that, then go to the US authorities for a new visa and explain the problem, supported by wHatever Hukou documentation you have.

Comment: If both your visa and your passport have the same date of birth, what's the problem? The US doesn't care what your hukou says.

Comment: My current passport is still valid for the next 6 years. Problem is, when I renewed it, the date of birth will be different than I currently have.